# How to preserve query params using <Route> in React Router V6?

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I don't see any mention of a "search" parameter on Route
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route

Currently, at least for my project, params are lost when a new route is matched and applied.

Does anyone know the best way of ensuring any existing search params are re-applied after a route change?

Comment: The `Route` component doesn't concern itself with the queryString, it uses ***only*** the path part of a URL for route matching. If the queryString is getting stripped off it's likely something your app is doing. Do you have any layout routes handling any redirects? Can you share your routing code and any other components that update the URL/navigate/etc as part of a [mcve]?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what the original question was asking, but here's an example of how using <Link> and navigate with to only results in loss of the query parameters. I'd be interested in knowing if there's a way of changing route parameters and preserving query parameters, without having to read and recreate them: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hr87x1?file=src%2FApp.tsx